# how to compare a date with system date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to put a validation check that compares the date (ex:12-jun-2015) with the current system date in javascript. I am able to compare the date and year,but since the month is in the 'mon' format, so I am not able to compare with system date.

```
var date =  new Date();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
var dateFields = (document.getElementById('startDate1').value.split('-'));
var screenMonth = dateFields[1];
```

Please suggest

Comment: Please add your code over here and comment i will help you http://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/n2mqezdq/

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using a month array containing all months code in 'mon' format.

```
var month = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec'];
var date = new Date();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth(); 
var dateFields = (document.getElementById('startDate1').value.split('-'));
var screenMonth = dateFields[1];
if(sceenMonth.toLowerCase()==month[currentMonth]) 
 // same month
else
 // not same month
```